# Ubuntu 20.04 changing brightness

Tags: dell, brightness, dell-vostro

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new Dell Vostro and I'm facing a screen brightness issue. It seems that the brightness is adjusted based on the current window. If it's brighter, the rest of the screen (like the bottom bar) gets darker, and the other way around. Consequently, it is most apparent when selecting a text in terminal or in Intellij Idea (selecting text makes the background go darker).

See it in action here:
https://makeagif.com/gif/ubuntu-brightness-afO1vb

For some reason it's way less visible here than in real life, but you should get an idea about the issue. I tried a bunch of things, but none of them worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7501, and I experienced the same "issue" both on Ubuntu 20.04 and Pop!_Os 20.04.

I have BIOS version 1.4.1 and I found there the option "Eco Power" or something like that on Display settings. I disabled that and It worked for me.

Edit: Actually there is the possibility of upgrading the BIOS to newer version, 1.5.1. I am not sure which version you have, but I hope they did not change the name of that option above.

Comment: Indeed, that was the culprit. Many thanks.

Comment: @meliniak You are welcome! I suggest you to edit the question tags and add dell because it is specific for Dell laptops. It may be found more easily for dell users searching for the same problem.